# CMake's find_path finds path on Windows but not on macOS

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

I have a cmake project for a third-party library which targets both Windows and macOS (let's call it `Foo`) which I hope to include with a cmake Find module.  The library stashes its includes in `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/include/Foo`, and I'm calling `find_path` to define `Foo_INCLUDE_DIR` as follows:

```
find_path(Foo_INCLUDE_DIR
        NAMES "Foo/version.hpp"
        PATHS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/include"
        NO_DEFAULT_PATH
        )
```

Now, the problem is that even though the project has the same exact dir tree on both macOS and Windows, the above call sets `Foo_INCLUDE_DIR` as `Foo_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND"`.

Does anyone have any idea why the above call to `find_path` only works on Windows?

Comment: Probably, the path `ThirdParty/include/Foo` differs from the actual one in case. On Windows paths are **case-insensitive**, so it accepts that path. BTW, if you know the exact include directory, no needs to call `find_path` for locate it. Just use that directory in `target_include_directories` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for chiming in.  Great call on not needing to call `find_path` to locate a file that I already know is there.